# How can I reuse typescript generics expressions?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

Is there some way to reuse a generic expression, so I can do something like this:

```js
alias TDoc = T extends { _id: string }

function doingSomething<TDoc>(x: TDoc): {
    console.log(x._id);
};

function doingSomethingElse<TDoc>(x: TDoc): {
    console.log(x._id);
};
```

For several functions or even other types.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this.  Can you motivate this with a better example?  I mean, you can write `type X = {_id: string}` and then `doingSomething<T extends X>(x: T) :...`, so at best you're saving the keystrokes in `extends X`, which doesn't seem like a huge win.

Comment: Is really just that, saving a few keystrokes, so I guess this is as far as it gets, thank you!